# Parse.com : how to join 2 tables?

Tags: ios, join, parse-platform

I'm a new user of `Parse.com`. I have a question about joining classes. Easy with SQL, but I don't find the solution with Parse. Thanks for your help !

I have 2 classes : `ProductDatabase` and `MachineDatabase`.

- **ProductDatabase** contains 4 columns : *serialNumber*, *name*, *description*, *price*.
- **MachineDatabase** contains 3 columns : *serialNumber*, *date*, *idMachine*.

I want to display the following datas : name, description, price, date.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *productQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ProductDatabase"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MachineDatabase"];
    [query whereKey:@"serialNumber" matchesKey:@"serialNumber" inQuery:productQuery];
    [query includeKey:@"name"];
    [query includeKey:@"description"];
    [query includeKey:@"price"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"date"];

    return query;
}

// In my (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object

cell.nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"description"];
cell.priceLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"price"];

NSDate *productDate = [object objectForKey:@"date"];
NSString * dateString = [self timeSincePublished:productDate];
cell.dateLabel.text = dateString;
```

This code displays the date, but not the name, description, price.

Do you know how I can join these two classes ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking it in an RDBS way and it is not ideal for a tool like Parse. You might need a little restructuring of your schema. Ideally, you should try using the Pointers in Parse (assuming your's is a one to many or one to one relation).

So your class structure will be like:

ProductDatabase: objectId, serialNumber, name, description, price, ***machine***
MachineDatabase: objectId, serialNumber, date, idMachine

If serialNumber is not specific to Product and Machine, you can keep it in any one class. The field '***machine***' in ProductDatabase should be an object pointer to the particular row in MachineDatabase.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ProductDatabase"];
[query includeKey:@"machine"];
```

***includeKey*** keyword will expand the relational field ***machine*** and add the fields for the respective row in MachineDatabase into the result.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *products, NSError *error) {

    for (PFObject *product in products) {
         // Machine row will be an object inside the retrieved product row. 
         PFObject *machine = product[@"machine"];
         NSLog(@"retrieved related machine: %@", machine);
    }
}];
```